# getting latest event for each eventtype from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with events, their time stamps and some errorcode and would like to get the latest occurrence for each of them. I am using oracle sql

```
TS    eventType    code
t1    A            1
t2    A            5
t3    BA           2
t4    A            1
t5    B            3
t6    B            1
t7    ZA            - 
t8    A            1
```

Assuming that t is strictly increasing, I am looking for a query that returns for each eventType A,B,C,... the latest event.

```
TS    eventType    code
t3    BA           2
t6    B            1
t7    ZA            - 
t8    A            1
```

My natural approach would be to loop and union, but there seem to be no straightforward ways to loop so I was hoping there would be another way that is more in the spirit of oracle sql to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the method is,

```
SELECT ts, eventtype, code
  FROM table_name t1
 WHERE ts = (SELECT MAX(ts)
               FROM table_name  t2
              WHERE t1.eventtype = t2.eventtype);
```

Or you can use `MAX()` analytic function to do this,

```
SELECT ts, eventtype, code
FROM(
     SELECT ts, 
            eventtype, 
            code,
            MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY eventtype) dt
     FROM   t
     )
WHERE ts = dt
ORDER BY ts;
```

Comment: I used the top approach and it worked nively. thanks Dba

Answer (score 0):

Analytical functions are the most efficient method (lowest cost execution plan) I've found to solve this and also have very simple syntax that does not require nested `SELECT`s and allows you to `ORDER BY` multiple columns easily.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da495/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( TS, eventType, code ) AS
          SELECT 't1', 'A', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 't2', 'A', 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 't3', 'BA', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 't4', 'A', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 't5', 'B', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 't6', 'B', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 't7', 'ZA', NULL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 't8', 'A', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MAX( ts   ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ts ) AS ts,
       eventType,
       MAX( code ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ts ) AS code
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY eventType
ORDER BY ts
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da495/1/0)**:

```
| TS | EVENTTYPE |   CODE |
|----|-----------|--------|
| t3 |        BA |      2 |
| t6 |         B |      1 |
| t7 |        ZA | (null) |
| t8 |         A |      1 |
```